# invalid identifier error in oracle due to column alias

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query as follows

```
select t.col1,
 t.col2,
 (select count(col1)
  from tab 
  where col1 = t.col1
        and col2 = t.col2
   ) as col3 
from tab t
where col3 > 1
```

The query gives an 'col3 invalid identifier' error.

I have tried different variations defining the alias which I have given below and the error I get when I use them

1. ```
   select t.col1,
          t.col2,
          (select count(col1)
           from tab 
           where col1 = t.col1
             and col2 = t.col2
          ) as "col3" 
   from tab t
   where col3 > 1
   ```

Error: col3 invalid identifier

1. ```
   select t.col1,
          t.col2,
          (select count(col1)
           from tab 
           where col1 = t.col1
             and col2 = t.col2
           ) as 'col3' 
   from tab t
   where [col3] > 1
   ```

Error: Missing expression after where

1. ```
   select t.col1,
          t.col2,
          (select count(col1)
           from tab 
           where col1 = t.col1
             and col2 = t.col2
          ) "col3" 
   from tab t
   where [col3] > 1
   ```

Error: Missing expression after where

Please explain me what the errors are about

P.S. I don't know why I am unable to mark the query examples as code here. I apologize for the poor readability of those queries

Comment: It took me a while myself to discover that trick. If you are "inside" a list (e.g. using `*` or `#`) you need to indent by 8 spaces to make it a "code block" - not with 4 spaces as you do normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your main problem is that you can't access a column alias on the same "nesting level". In order to be able to use the alias you need to wrap the whole query in a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  select t.col1,
         t.col2,
         (select count(col1)
          from tab 
          where col1 = t.col1
            and col2 = t.col2
         ) as col3 
  from tab t
) 
where col3 > 1
```

Your "numbered" examples would not work for two reasons: first for the above reason and secondly because identifiers that are quoted using double quotes become case-sensitive. So `"col3"` is a different column name than `"Col3"`. As Oracle folds unquoted identifiers to uppercase (following the requirements of the SQL standard) `col3` would be equivalent to `"COL3"`

Finally: `[col3]` is an invalid identifier in SQL regardless if you use it as a column alias or not. Identifiers must be quoted using double quotes. Those square brackets are invalid in SQL

Comment: Thank you. Greatly appreciate the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a column alias in a `WHERE` clause, only in an `ORDER BY` clause. You have two options.

One, you can wrap you entire query in another select and then filter on col3:

```
select * from (
select t.col1,
 t.col2,
 (select count(col1)
  from tab 
  where col1 = t.col1
        and col2 = t.col2
   ) as col3 
from tab t)
where col3 > 1;
```

Or you can repeat the scalar subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select t.col1,
 t.col2,
 (select count(col1)
  from tab 
  where col1 = t.col1
        and col2 = t.col2
   ) as col3 
from tab t
where (select count(col1)
  from tab 
  where col1 = t.col1
        and col2 = t.col2
   ) > 1;
```

I suggest option 1 myself.

Comment: "You cannot use a column alias in a WHERE clause" but whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy -.-

Comment: @ryvantage because WHERE will be executed before the SELECT statement, so the alias isn't known at this step